# undefined method `first_name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, tire

I've implemented search using Tire and ElasticSearch – everything has been working great.

I have three models: Posts, Publications and Users. Users have many Posts through Publications.

Using tire, I've made Posts searchable. However, I now want the Posts and the Post's user to be searchable. This is where things break.

Below is my Post model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name, :tag_list, :thumbnail_image, :status, :post_type, :subtitle, :summary, :visibility, :user
  acts_as_taggable

  has_one :publication
  has_one :user, :through => :publication
  has_many :subscriptions, dependent: :destroy


  has_many :channel_post_connections, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :channels, :through => :channel_post_connections

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :channel_post_connections
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :channels
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :publication
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user


  has_many :post_pages, dependent: :destroy

  validates_presence_of :post_type, :name, :subtitle, :tag_list, :summary, :thumbnail_image, :if => :post_is_published?


  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks
  index_name 'posts_index'


  def self.search(params)
    tire.search(load: true) do
        query { string params[:query], default_operator: "AND" } if params[:query].present? 
      sort { by :created_at, "desc" } if params[:query].blank?
    end
  end

  def to_indexed_json
    to_json(methods: [:user_first_name, :user_display_name])
  end

  def user_first_name
    user.first_name
  end

  def user_display_name
    user.display_name
  end

end
```

Things seem to fall apart at the to_indexed_json method, here's the error I receive when I try to create a new post:

```
NoMethodError in PostsController#create
undefined method `first_name' for nil:NilClass
```

I'm not certain why this is happening – the Class should be "User", and, first_name is a valid column in the Users table, with a legitimate value.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: try to inspect user and publication inside `user_first_name` (something like `p self, publication, user`) and check that the relation works

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the user for the post is not nil? Also, you might want to look into delegates for the methods your creating to call attributes for users. http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate

Comment: Thanks so much for the help – there are values, where necessary. It looks as though the issue was actually my reference in the model itself. I changed user.first_name to "self.user.first_name if self.user.present?" – and this seems to have solved the issue.